# Problems with an if else statement looping through worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I been trying to write a code which should do the following: loop through tabs in sheet and if a fixed cell (3,7) contains a name a counter should receive +1. So if a certain name is filled in in three tabs in cell (3,7) the counter should be three.

I tried to get this working by the following code:

```
Public davidCount As Integer

Sub Count()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_count As Integer

davidCount = 0
ws_count = Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_count

//perform function
countDavid

Next i


MsgBox (davidCount)

Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 5) = davidCount

End Sub
```

With function:

```
Function countDavid() As String

If Cells(7, 3) = "David Stam" Then
davidCount = davidCount + 1
End If


End Function
```

If i do a quick sanity check my code does not work however. I receive a value a 16 while I David is only inserted in three tabs....

Any quick thoughts on what goes wrong?

Regards,

Marc

Comment: how many worksheet are there in your workbook? Have you tried to pass worksheet to your CountDavid() function to make sure you are fully qualifying your worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through each sheet in the workbook as below and increase a counter without a separate function:

```
Public Sub Count()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Loop through each worksheet in the current workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'If the cell contains David Stam, increment i by 1
    If ws.Cells(7, 3) = "David Stam" Then
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next ws

MsgBox i

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 5) = i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant `Next ws` rather than `Next i` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have 16 worksheets and the name is also on the first one?

You seem to miss switching to worksheet number i. And for the pre-selected first worksheet the condition is always true.